# Switch/Case - Expected Member name or ";" after declaration specifiers

Tags: c++

"Expected Member name or ";" after declaration specifiers" error appear on the top line  switch(stuff)

```
 float waveform = getParameter(6);

switch(waveform){
    case 1: Sine signalGenerator
        break;
    case 2: SawWave signalGenerator
        break;
    case 3: SquareWave signalGenerator
        break;
    default: Sine signalGenerator
}
```

Any suggestions on how to sort it would be great! Thanks in advance!

This is the real code:

```
float waveform = getParameter(6); 
switch(waveform)
{ case 1: Sine signalGenerator break; 
  case 2: SawWave signalGenerator break; 
  case 3: SquareWave signalGenerator break; 
  default: Sine signalGenerator 
}
```

Comment: What should this mean: `case 1: stuff 1` ?? `stuff 1` simply isn't valid syntax, did you mean to put a comment there: `case 1: // stuff 1`?

Comment: Have you declared `stuff` before this switch/case?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This is the real code:

float waveform = getParameter(6);
    
    switch(waveform){
        case 1: Sine signalGenerator
            break;
        case 2: SawWave signalGenerator
            break;
        case 3: SquareWave signalGenerator
            break;
        default: Sine signalGenerator
    }

Comment: First of all, you cannot switch on a `float`. Second, `Sine signalGenerator break;` is a syntax error; a declaration must end with a semicolon. Third, you are declaring multiple objects of the same name in the same scope which is also an error.

Answer (score 2):

what you want is probably this:

```
int waveform = (int) getParameter(6);
WaveBase* sigGen;
switch(waveform) {
    case 1:  sigGen = new Sine; break; 
    case 2:  sigGen = new SawWave; break;
    case 3:  sigGen = new SquareWave; break; 
    default: sigGen = new Sine;
}

// use  sigGen here

delete sigGen;
```

this assumes that Sine, SawWave and SquareWave have a common base (they should)
and that its destructor is virtual (it should)